What happened with the Babylonians?
In the 2008 movie Body of Lies, when Ferris is visited by his boss, Ed Hoffman, they have the following dialogue:

- You know, they say you should never drink red wine in the desert?
- That's what did in the Babylonians, right?
- Well, couple bottles of that and we'll be speaking Babylonian.

What is this reference about? Something biblical? Couldn't find a good confirmation on Google.

This is a reference to Revelation 14:8

And there followed another angel, saying, “Babylon is fallen! Fallen
is that great city, because she made all nations drink of the wine of
the wrath of her fornication.”


Purely for the record, the wine of Babylon wasn't literal wine. The angel is referring to 'spiritual drunkenness' rather than literally over-indulging with alcohol.
